# Deleting rows that match certain columns between two spreadsheets in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple question that i'm hoping you all can help with.

I have two spreadsheets:

Spreadsheet A:

```
| First name | Last name | Address | Email           |
|------------|-----------|---------|-----------------|
| Bob        | Torn      | 1 Lane  | bob@bob.com     |
| Tina       | Torn      | 1 Lane  | tina@tina.com   |
| Candace    | Candy     | 5 Lane  | candy@candy.com
```

Spreadsheet B:

```
| First name | Last name | Address  | Email           |
|------------|-----------|----------|-----------------|
| Bob        | Torn      | 1 Lane   | bob@bob.com     |
| Tina       | Torn      | 1 Lane   | tina@tina.com   |
| Brian      | Powers    | 6 Street | brian@brian.com |
| Alfred     | Cruse     | 7 Street | alfie@alfie.com |
```

I'd like to somehow have pandas look at both tables and end up with a result like this:
Spreadsheet A:

```
| First name | Last name | Address  | Email           |
|------------|-----------|----------|-----------------|
| Candace    | Candy     | 5 Lane   | candy@candy.com |
| Brian      | Powers    | 6 Street | brian@brian.com |
| Alfred     | Cruse     | 7 Street | alfie@alfie.com |
|            |           |          |                 |
```

So basically, if First name, Last name, Address in Spreadsheet A match First name, Last name, in Spreadsheet B, delete the row from Spreadsheet A.

I've gotten the merge to work using this:

```
mergedData = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['First name', 'Last name')
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take that data and then erase it from spreadsheet A.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = dfA.merge(dfB, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True)
df1=df[df['_merge'].ne('both')]

    Firstname Lastname  Address            Email      _merge
2   Candace    Candy    5Lane  candy@candy.com   left_only
3     Brian   Powers  6Street  brian@brian.com  right_only
4    Alfred    Cruse  7Street  alfie@alfie.com  right_only
```

Comment: This doesn't return all the neccesary rows, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Please see my edits. Happy to help further